# create Eagle library for bsdl file

Tags: pcb, fpga, intel-fpga

I am designing a PCB Board for Altera Cyclone III EP3C5E144. However, I cant find any library for this device in Eagle.

Is there anyways I could create the library and symbol for this device, based on this bsdl file?

http://bsdl.info/view.htm?sid=599926c619a107a388ca59b002289d77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eagle comes with an ULP for this. It's called "make-symbol-device-package-bsdl.ulp" .

Open a new library file. From menu click File->Run, select make-symbol-device-package-bsdl.ulp . Click Browse, find your *.bsdl file. Rest should be easy..

Answer (score 1):

Since Eagle 6.0 I think all the source files (libraries included) are XML. If you were so inclined, I imagine you could convert from the BSDL files to the required XML format programatically (it's all just structured ASCII text after all). You can find the DTD (structure definition) file in the EAGLE docs/ subdirectory of the installation. I doubt anybody has bother to do a BSDL -> EAGLE XML converter tool, but I've been wrong before once or twice.